# How to merge two arrays of objects of the same kind and operate on a certain field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, maps

I have two arrays of objects of the same structure.
Array 1 contains elements such as:

```
[
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "XX",
            displayName: "XX",
            count: 12
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            name: "XX",
            displayName: "XX",
            count: 12
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            name: "XX",
            displayName: "XX",
            count: 12
        }
    ]
```

Array 2 contains elements such as:

```
[
        {
            id: "1",
            count: 2
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            count: 5
        }
    ]
```

I need a resulting array of this type:

```
[
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "XX",
            displayName: "XX",
            count: 10
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            name: "XX",
            displayName: "XX",
            count: 12
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            name: "XX",
            displayName: "XX",
            count: 7
        }
    ]
```

That means I need a new array containing all items from array1 with that same structure, but if in array 2 i have a matching ID the new count should be the difference between the value of the two, otherwise it is unchanged.
I have been trying to implement this using .reduce() but I am having some trouble getting the logic together, can anyone shed some light on how should I think this through? I am fairly new to JS and I come from a mostly C99 and Python background.

I am excluding the use of nested for loops for this for obvious reasons.
A solution I had in mind was to make all the "count" values in in the second array negative, and using this other method I found on this [same website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516631/sum-data-from-two-array-of-objects). This solution also implies all attributes are int values and sums them all up:

```
        const sumItem = ({ id, ...a }, b) => ({
            id,
            ...Object.keys(a)
                .reduce((r, k) => ({ ...r, [k]: a[k] + b[k] }), {})
            });
        

        const sumObjectsByKey = (...arrs) => [...
            [].concat(...arrs) // combine the arrays
                .reduce((m, o) => // retuce the combined arrays to a Map
                    m.set(o.id, // if add the item to the Map
                        m.has(o.id) ? subItem(m.get(o.id), o) : { ...o } // if the item exists in Map, sum the current item with the one in the Map. If not, add a clone of the current item to the Map
                    )
                    , new Map).values()]
```

But that does not feel elegant or "right", and I feel like I should instead focus on understanding methods related to maps a bit better. Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two arrays and sum values of duplicate objects using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884760/how-to-merge-two-arrays-and-sum-values-of-duplicate-objects-using-lodash)

Comment: or [How to merge two array and sum their value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710800/how-to-merge-two-array-and-sum-their-value)

Comment: No merge needed, you are going through the elements of arr2 and updating the corresponding element in arr1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to an intermediate object and take the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of that:

```js
const array1 = [{
  id: "1",
  name: "XX",
  displayName: "XX",
  count: 12
}, {
  id: "2",
  name: "XX",
  displayName: "XX",
  count: 12
}, {
  id: "3",
  name: "XX",
  displayName: "XX",
  count: 12
}];

const array2 = [{
  id: "1",
  count: 2
}, {
  id: "3",
  count: 5
}];

const result = Object.values([...array1, ...array2].reduce((a, v) => {
  if (a[v.id]) a[v.id].count -= v.count
  else a[v.id] = { ...v }
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Appreciate this solution, worked flawlessly and this was exactly what I was looking for. Written out with my own case this also really helped me understand better how it works and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `Array#map` to create the array with updated counts and `Array#find` to get the matching element by id from the second array (if any) on each iteration.

```js
let arr1=[{id:"1",name:"XX",displayName:"XX",count:12},{id:"2",name:"XX",displayName:"XX",count:12},{id:"3",name:"XX",displayName:"XX",count:12}],
    arr2=[{id:"1",count:2},{id:"3",count:5}];
let res = arr1.map(o => ({...o, count : o.count - 
  (arr2.find(x => o.id === x.id)?.count ?? 0)}));
console.log(res);
```

A more efficient method would be to first create an object that maps each id in the second array to its count, then use those counts when generating the new array.

```js
let arr1=[{id:"1",name:"XX",displayName:"XX",count:12},{id:"2",name:"XX",displayName:"XX",count:12},{id:"3",name:"XX",displayName:"XX",count:12}],
    arr2=[{id:"1",count:2},{id:"3",count:5}];
let counts2 = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = curr.count;
  return acc;
}, {});
let res = arr1.map(o => ({...o, count : o.count - (counts2[o.id] ?? 0)}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I appreciate you for contributing, I began understanding better the logic behind it. I am also curious about the efficiency comparison: is it due to "coding etiquette" or are there computational reasons behind it? Thank you